# In ms-rest-azure, when I try to get authentication token, how do I specify resource?

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

So I am trying to get authentication to keyvault:

```
import * as msRestAzure from 'ms-rest-azure';
msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(clientID, clientKey, domainID);
```

How do I specify the resource to be "https://vault.azure.net"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use  `msRestAzure.loginWithAppServiceMSImsRestAzure.loginWithAppServiceMSI({resource: 'https://vault.azure.net'});`

You could check this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-node/).

```
function getKeyVaultCredentials(){
    return msRestAzure.loginWithAppServiceMSI({resource: 'https://vault.azure.net'});
}

function getKeyVaultSecret(credentials) {
    let keyVaultClient = new KeyVault.KeyVaultClient(credentials);
    return keyVaultClient.getSecret(KEY_VAULT_URI, 'secret', "");
}

getKeyVaultCredentials().then(
    getKeyVaultSecret
).then(function (secret){
    console.log(`Your secret value is: ${secret.value}.`);
}).catch(function (err) {
    throw (err);
});
```

Comment: If you create key vault and secret, you could replace resource to `https://management.core.windows.net/`. I think it also works.

Comment: You also could use `const rp = require('request-promise');` to do this, see this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity#obtaining-tokens-for-azure-resources).

Comment: Hi, does it work for you? Please let me know if you need more future help.

Comment: Not sure, we shelved this project, I will mark this as resolved.